# flatten a list/array from Dstream in pyspark streaming

Tags: python, arrays, apache-spark, pyspark, streaming

I'm consuming a Kafka topic with spark streaming and I need to count all the occurrences of values in an array.  It is similar to the canonical word count examples, except that my input data is a list of strings.   Full disclosure:  I'm new to all things spark.

```
["#epstein", "#didnt", "#kill", "#himself"]
["#foo", "#didnt", "#bar"]
```

needs to become something like

```
#epstein  1
#foo 1
#didnt 2
#kill 1
#himself 1
#bar 1
```

I can get this far, extracting the hashtag array from the rest of the kafka message and can print out the array to the console, but I can't figure out how to split/count it.

```
zookeeper = '10.0.8.111:2181'
kafka_topic = 'twitter_short_json'

sc = SparkContext(appName="CountHashtags")
sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")

# sets the stream to run in 5 second increments
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 5)

kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zookeeper, 'streaming-group', {kafka_topic: 1})

# parse the Kafka stream as json, returns a DStream object
hashtagsDStream = kafkaStream.map(lambda x: x[1]) \
                         .map(lambda j: json.loads(j)) \
                         .map(lambda p: ((p['hashtags']),))
hashtagsDStream.pprint()
```

If I had an RDD, I could use the explode method like this:

```
exploded = hashtagsDStream.withColumn("hashtags", explode(hashtagsDStream.hashtags))

exploded.registerTempTable('exploded_table')
sqlDF = sqlContext.sql('select count(*), hashtags from exploded_table group by hashtags order by 1 desc').show()
```

But DStream doesn't have a withColumn method so I'm stuck on how to do counts on the actual hashtag values from the array.

Answer (score 1):

`DStream` is a stream of `RDD`. You can call `hashtagsDStream.foreachRDD(rdd ... )` and there write what you want to do with each rdd you will receive.